# removing php session timeout

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, session

I'm looking to remove the timeout on php sessions on my site. the result of:

```
var_dump(ini_get('session.save_path')); var_dump(ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime')); var_dump(ini_get('session.cookie_lifetime'));
```

Is *string(13) "/var/lib/php5" string(4) "1440" string(1) "0"*

According to the forums I've seen, with session.cookie_lifetime set to 0 timeout should already be unlimited shouldn't it?

So two questions:
Which values do I need to set to remove session timeout?
And also... I understand I need to put code into .htaccess but where does the .htaccess need to be to take effect on php sessions?

Comment: Why are your doing this? anytime someone clears their browser cache it will reset their session as they will loose the cookie.  Why do you want to remove the session timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure about how PHP session garbage collection works, but I'm not sure that you can completely eliminate it.  If you want to retain the session, put some JS on the page that periodically makes requests to keep the session fresh.  If your concern is keeping people logged in for even longer than that (perhaps after browser closing) you can use [your own cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591728/designing-a-secure-auto-login-cookie-system-in-php/7591897#7591897).

Comment: the page is used to modify large database tables so I'm not wanting to completely refresh, what code would be sufficient to keep the session alive without being a nuisance to the user?

Comment: @KellyLarsen you don't have to refresh that page itself, you can have some other page that does nothing but start the session and just ping that every few minutes or something.

Comment: just had an idea, if I call a php page that regenerates the session id every 5 mins... that would reduce session hijacking too wouldn't it?  kill two birds with one stone...
function KeepAlive()
{
setTimeout("CallServer()", 50);
}

function CallServer()
{
call regen.php
}
</SCRIPT>

Comment: that didn't go to plan... something like this one http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20060828142142AAxwqZZ

Comment: you could also do it with an iframe that includes an html file with a meta refresh.  If you're using jQuery, their ajax handling is a lot easier.