# Correct way to store passwords for autologin

Tags: security, authentication, passwords

I get how to store passwords on a server, but what about a client that will automatically login to the server? What's the best way here? Should I store a hashed password, and have the server double hash? Should I encrypt it? What options are available?

This software will be open source, so any keys used are publicly available.

EDIT:

This is actually a computer program. I can send stuff off like MAC addresses without a problem.

Comment: Most clients, whether desktop PCs or mobile devices, already have the ability to store credentials securely... Is there a reason you need to build this functionality yourself?

Comment: No, I'm using Qt. I'll look into it.

Comment: Yeah Qt offers something like this as well. Good luck with it

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the level of security you want to reach :-)
Also look here where this topic is discussed in detail: [Designing a secure auto login cookie system in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591728/designing-a-secure-auto-login-cookie-system-in-php)

Edit: Even more detailled http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice
and yet another very very good post about the whole topic: [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication#477579) look at PART II

Answer (score -2):

As far as I'm concerned, cookies are sufficiently safe to save the password in cleartext. It is only a problem if you have an XSS leak or someone saves it on a public computer, so another person can look it up.

In that case, I would go for the solution you suggested with hash on clientside and double hash on serverside.

EDIT: I just realized, that they can be read out (with ease) when using an (unsecured) WLAN, too, so now it seems to be a bad idea to save them in cleartext.

Comment: You should NEVER store passwords in plaintext in a cookie. This is just crazy talk.